# Count the total objects selected/checked inside a pivot table filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which data can be filtered by selecting multiple months.
The first row are a set of objects I would like to see the value for, and these are very unlikely to change. Second row would be the total value for each object depending on the month/s selected.

My objective is then to get an average value depending on the number of months selected in the pivot filter. (e.g., if I selected Jan/16, Feb/16, and March/16 it would result in "3" as the basis for division)

There was a similar question to mine but it never got a relevant answer ([Find the number of checked elements of a pivot table filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266902/find-the-number-of-checked-elements-of-a-pivot-table-filter))

Comment: Can you give a bigger example? I have a hard time visioning what this pivot table actually looks like.

Comment: Something like this, is this clearer?

http://imgur.com/a/b66A7

xx are just random values which would be divided by the number of months selected/checked. Thanks!